# AMD GPU not being detected or used at all

Tags: amdgpu

I have run into a problem where video applications that normally run fine, including Zoom and Discord (as well as Blender renders), cause extreme stuttering in my whole system. After some digging around I found that my GPU was not being used at all, and my CPU was taking the entire load.

Running `lspci | grep VGA` brings up `01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] (rev cf)`, however on my System Profiler there is no mention of this Graphics Card anywhere that I can find, nor is it listed in CoreCtrl (I can only see the CPU). I know the graphics card is installed correctly, because on Windows 10 I am able to see my CPU (fx-4300) and GPU (rx-460) through their software.

I have tried installing their AMD drivers for Ubuntu 20.04.1 64-bit (the version I am running), but all the installations inevitably end up with Errors were encountered while processing: amdgpu-dkms amdgpu. I have tried adding the oibaf ppa, updating and upgrading, then restarting, but neither CoreCtrl nor System Profiler have been able to see my GPU.

Could anyone help me with this? It's really annoying because my webcam only works well on Linux, but Zoom ends up taking 60%+ of my CPU running in the background and it makes doing most processes much slower on Ubuntu vs. Windows.

By request: the output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` is

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] (rev cf) Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Baffin [Radeon RX 460/560D / Pro 450/455/460/555/555X/560/560X] Kernel modules: amdgpu 01:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Baffin HDMI/DP Audio [Radeon RX 550 640SP / RX 560/560X]`

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Regarding Zoom. most likely you won't get any hardware acceleration on Linux no matter which GPU is used.

Comment: @Pilot6 Ok, I have done as requested. This is not a Zoom exclusive problem however, I am encountering extremely bad stuttering for my whole computer during a Discord call wtih video, and I have noticed my Blender renderings on Linux generally perform much worse than on windows.